# TextBox fill all space

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I try to develop simple WebBrowser with tabs. Just for experience.
So i want to add TextBox for URL user input.
On designer with small size of window this all ok(Screenshot 1).
But when i Maximize window, TextBox dont fit all space(ScreenShot 2).
I use StackPanel. Maybe better to use another control?

I try to play with Stretch HorizontalAligment but it didnt work.
[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jiyh0.png)
[ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1jBD.png)

Comment: You can use grid panel

Comment: But i use WPF, theres no anchor properties.

Comment: You should start thinking in xaml rather than the visual designer. Then post the relevant xaml and not only images of what you have and get answers how the xaml can be modified to meet your criteria ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Grid` with an appropriate number of columns, or a `DockPanel` like this:

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Content="Home" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Button Content="Back" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Button Content="Next" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Button Content="Refresh" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="Go" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="Menu" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" />
</DockPanel>
```

By default, the last elements fills all remaining space.

Comment: OK it works, thanks very much!